# How to configure a RedHat 6 server to always use the gateway?

Tags: linux, networking, redhat

In one of my datacenters, I need to configure the server to only speak to the gateway even if the other server is in the same network...

How can I configure the network card ? I suppose something with a /32 mask.

Server IP:  x.x.x.36
Gateway IP: x.x.x.33

EDIT: I have several servers to configure in the same way. So, the answer of Gene cannot work.

Server IP's : x.x.x.34 - 35 - 51 - 52 - 54

Thanks,

Bob !

Comment: What's the reason ?

Comment: My provider asks to use only the gateway for security purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new subnet (something small like a /30) for the system you want all traffic goinging through the router.  For example:

Router:

- **IP**: 192.168.2.1
- **Netmask**: 255.255.255.252

Server:

- **IP**: 192.168.2.2
- **Netmask**: 255.255.255.252
- **Gateway**: 192.168.2.1

This way when 192.168.2.2 needs to talk to anything in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet (and vice versa) it has to go through the router to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot but that will not work. The public Ip's of my servers are x.x.x.34 - 35 - 36 -51 - 52 - 54  & the gateway x.x.x.33. I want to each server speaks only with the gateway. Like as said, my provider wants this setup for security reasons...